# VBA to Move raw from source sheet to different sheets based on different columns

Tags: vba

Dears, Am new in VBA, here below i create this vba macro for my work needs, to distribute data rows from Sheet1 to different sheets (2,3,4,5) & list sheet (6) based on:
if cell value in sheet1 column A match with sheet6 column A then move raw from sheet1 to sheet2
if cell value in sheet1 column A match with sheet6 column B then move raw from sheet1 to sheet3
and so on.
but my code took long time (very slow)
need your help please.

---

```
    Sub distribute()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Base As Worksheet 
    Dim List As Worksheet 
    Dim i As Integer 
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set Base = Sheets(1)
    Set List = Sheets(7)

    LastRow = Base.Cells(Base.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    For b = 2 To LastRow

    If Base.Cells(i, 2).Value = List.Cells(b, 1).Value Then
    Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).EntireRow
             
    Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
    If Base.Cells(i, 2).Value = List.Cells(b, 2).Value Then
   Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy _
   Destination:=Sheets(3).Rows(Sheets(3).Cells(Sheets(3).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).EntireRow

   Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
   Else
   If Base.Cells(i, 2).Value = List.Cells(b, 3).Value Then
   Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy _
   Destination:=Sheets(4).Rows(Sheets(4).Cells(Sheets(4).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).EntireRow

   Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
   Else
   If Base.Cells(i, 2).Value = List.Cells(b, 4).Value Then
   Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy _
   Destination:=Sheets(5).Rows(Sheets(5).Cells(Sheets(5).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).EntireRow

   Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
    End If
    End If
    End If

    Next b
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't use .Copy- that really slows down performance

Comment: Thank you @Andy - what's your suggestion PLS.

Comment: how big are the datasets you are dealing with on each sheet?

Comment: Around 100 rows

Comment: by how many columns?

Comment: sorry, 9 columns

Answer (score 0):

I run your code using some sample data sheet,  for me it runs fast enough. You may add these ff code to optimize you procedure.

```
    Sub distribute()
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.EnableEvents = False

.....rest of the code 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Another tip if you want. Try to use CUT instead of copy then you can delete the code:

```
Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

Use the cut instead of copy

```
If Base.Cells(i, 2).Value = List.Cells(b, 2).Value Then
Base.Rows(i).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Sheets(3).Rows(Sheets(3).Cells(Sheets(3).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).EntireRow
```

Comment: Thank you, but i feel no big diff. After apply these change.